# React Native: Touchable Opacity - Setting up custom transition duration as well as changing background color during transition period

Tags: android, react-native, transition, opacity, touchableopacity

We are using react-native to build an android application. We are having a screen where in there are 10 touchable opacity buttons of a numerical keypad. On press of any of the buttons of the keypad, we need to accomplish following 3 points.

1. Set the button opacity to 60%.
2. Change the background color to #FFFFFF during the transition period.
3. The duration of transition should be 0.8 seconds.

We are able to achieve point 1 from above using the "activeOpacity" property in touchable opacity. For point 2 and point 3, we are not able to change the transition duration or change the background color during the transition. Am I missing anything? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I think you should use TouchableWithFeedbask + Animated instead and create your own custom animations. TouchableOpacity are made for working such that way as a ready-for-use component.